# Cannot match my regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to match a string that looks like "WIFLYMODULE-xxxx" where the x can be any digit. For example, I want to be able to find the following...
WIFLYMODULE-3253
WIFLYMODULE-1585
WIFLYMODULE-1632

I am currently using

```
final Pattern q = Pattern.compile("[WIFLYMODULE]-[0-9]{3}");
```

but I am not picking up the string that I want. So my question is, why is my regular expression not working? Am i going about it in the wrong way?

Comment: what is expected output? share complete code.

Comment: okay, let me add it really quick

Comment: Wow, you guys are fast.

Comment: Also note that `[0-9]` is exactly `\\d`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `(..)` instead of `[...]`. `[..]` is used for [Character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

With a "character class", also called "character set", you can tell the regex engine to match only one out of several characters.

```
(WIFLYMODULE)-[0-9]{4}
```

Here is [demo](http://regex101.com/r/iT4eX9/8)

**Note:** But in this case it's not needed at all. `(...)` is used for capturing group to access it by `Matcher.group(index)`

---

**Important Note**: Use `\b` as *word boundary* to match the **correct word**.

```
\\bWIFLYMODULE-[0-9]{4}\\b
```

Sample code:

```
String str = "WIFLYMODULE-3253 WIFLYMODULE-1585 WIFLYMODULE-1632";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\bWIFLYMODULE-[0-9]{4}\\b");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

output:

```
WIFLYMODULE-3253
WIFLYMODULE-1585
WIFLYMODULE-1632
```

Comment: Might want to add an ending boundary so things like "WIFLYMODULE-3253asdf" and "WIFLYMODULE-32531234" don't match.

Comment: yes you are in right direction. Code is updated as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

This way will work:

```
final Pattern q = Pattern.compile("WIFLYMODULE-[0-9]{4}");
```

---

The pattern breaks down to:

```
WIFLYMODULE-         The literal string WIFLYMODULE-
[0-9]{4}             Exactly four digits
```

---

What you had was:

```
[WIFLYMODULE]        Any one of the characters in WIFLYMODULE
-                    The literal string -
[0-9]{3}             Exactly three digits
```

Answer (score 1):

The regex should be:

```
"WIFLYMODULE-[0-9]{4}"
```

The square brackets means: *one of the characters listed inside*. Also you were matching three numbers instead of four. So your were matching strings like (where `xxx` is a number of three digits):

```
W-xxx, I-xxx, F-xxx, L-xxx, Y-xxx, M-xxx, O-xxx, D-xxx, U-xxx, L-xxx, E-xxx
```

Answer (score 1):

You had it match on 3 digits instead of 4. And putting `WIFLYMODULE` inside `[]` makes it match on only one of those characters.

```
final Pattern q = Pattern.compile("WIFLYMODULE-[0-9]{4}");
```

Answer (score 1):

`[...]` means that one character out of the ones in the bracket must match and not the string within it.

You, however, want to match `WIFLYMODULE`, thus, you have to use `Pattern.compile("WIFLYMODULE-[0-9]{3}");` or `Pattern.compile("(WIFLYMODULE)-[0-9]{3}");`

`{n}` means that the character (or group) must match n-times. In your example you need 4 instead of 3: `Pattern.compile("WIFLYMODULE-[0-9]{4}");`